# Trouble retrieving a google docs presentation using curl and php

Tags: curl, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

The problem I am having  occurs when I try to access a published presentation using curl via php. Normal documents are accessible through curl but not presentations. I am looking to either make this method of retrieving the document work or find an alternative. A google support didn't have an answer for me and recommended stack overflow.

At first, attempting to access a presentation through curl gave me this error:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to develop.willf-rtb-dev.switchsoft.com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

I added a vhost for my testing domain on my development box to enable ssl. This vhost starts with the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

After adding this vhost, attempting to access the presentation through curl redirects me to this page:

https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32050 (telling me to clear my cookies due to a problem with my cookie settings)

I have my curl code writing too a cookie file -- the contents of this file are as follows after attempting to access the presentation through curl. Clearing the contents of the file does no good, and neither does telling curl not to write to this file.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.google.com    TRUE    /    FALSE    1380146248    NID    67=q47Xyj4FU2_uuYosZzvr_50-o2q9qD0PG8avG3oTg0s2qlmjzGFqT0UhWpwLOEt9TWqP1jf77npfX9OBebQ8fqn6ID7b4b-jBoFbyEbCFkrQhcBIKekLS1fQI-mLw3Pg
```

My php curl code looks like this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,3);

$cookieFile = TMP_DIRECTORY . '/curlcookies.txt';
if (!file_exists($cookieFile)) {
file_put_contents($cookieFile, '');
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.4");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

I have tried using this style of url to download the html of the presentation:

https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id=1RDANgsJWv841KvQUROKhyikTuwQGXC5Q1XFvXDwAfMw

This requires me to sign in and when I am signed it gives me this error:

```
Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.

Please check the address and try again.
```

I do not get this error when use exportFormat=pdf -- that works so long as I am signed in but it's not what I need.

I have not attempted to use it yet but I found some php code here which might be worth looking into:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

Any hints or help any one can give me on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards

Will Ferrer

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the export statement where you tried to export it as HTML

https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id=1RDANgsJWv841KvQUROKhyikTuwQGXC5Q1XFvXDwAfMw

Notice that in google presentation frontend, it only allows you export as pdf, pptx, txt, jpg, png, svg.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/v2/reference#ExportParameters

In the google documentation, it also states that values for presentations are the following only: "pdf", "png", and "ppt".

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the response. Reading my initial post I think I failed to make the issue completely clear. Currently I am not using the method you described above but instead I am just trying to access the published presentation by contacting it's published url via curl: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1RDANgsJWv841KvQUROKhyikTuwQGXC5Q1XFvXDwAfMw/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000. The method you described above is a method I was thinking of using as a fall back. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I think the URL that you are trying to access can only be accessed via browser.  In order to download the presentation, you should try to access https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?exportFormat=pdf&id=1RDANgsJWv841KvQUROKhyikTuwQGXC5Q1XFvXDwAfMw via curl.